# Java Thread Pool

Tags: java, threadpool

I want to learn to write a thread pool in Java

Can anyone point me to useful resources ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have a look at the source code for [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java.htm) from core java. Though why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 7):

take a look at Doug Lea's books... they are fairly old now (unless he released a new one, not sure), but the concurrent package added in 1.5 is based on his threading libraries.  as far as i am concerned, he is the authority on concurrent programming in java... his books will give you the basics of what you need to understand to accomplish this task.

i can only assume this is an academic exercise... if not, i would strongly recommend you stick to the concurrent package as it is well-tested and well-developed... don't re-invent the wheel.  good luck.

Comment: I strongly recommend this as well since Doug Lea was one of the primary developers that created the concurrency package in Java

Comment: I agree with Ascalonian. I took Doug Lea's concurrency course at Oswego and it was one of the best classes I ever took. (Next to compiler, which he also taught.) The book he recommends right now is "Java Concurrency in Practice" as amarillion said.

Comment: I haven't read that book... can't really go wrong with a list of authors like that though!  i just realized that Lea is listed on there... i didn't see it first time i looked.

Answer (score 6):

I definitely recommend reading "[concurrency in practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/)". It's the number one book dealing with threading issues in Java.

Answer (score 2):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Answer (score 1):

I agree that re-inventing wheel is not required and we should stick to Executor framework. But even i was curious to know how thread pool is implemented in Executor framework.

found this interesting link which talks how thread pool can be implemented in custom way using  threads : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html